# Grouping date's as 1 count if difference is 5 days

Tags: oracle

I am trying to think of a way of grouping some dates to make a count if they are more then 5 days apart.

For Example:

```
ID - DATE
22   15/05/2016 08:57
22   15/05/2016 10:50
22   15/05/2016 12:01
22   16/05/2016 01:12
22   22/05/2016 02:25
```

So for this I would currently get a count of 5 as there are 5 occurrences however I want to only get a count for 2 due to the fact that the first 4 have sequential dates and the final one is 5 days after the previous date so would need that counted as a new one.

Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: Is the 5 day gap measured from the first day of a set or the last day? E.g. would 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 be one set (all consecutive) or two (1+5 = 6, 7+5 > 9)? What about 2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, the following is the query that you are looking for.

```
SQL> select * from mytest;

        ID DT
---------- ---------
        22 15-MAY-17
        22 15-MAY-17
        22 15-MAY-17
        22 16-MAY-17
        22 22-MAY-17
        23 23-MAY-17
        23 25-MAY-17
        23 30-MAY-17

8 rows selected.

SQL> select id, count(diff)+1 count 
     from( 
          select id, dt - lag(dt) over(order by dt) diff 
          from mytest
          ) 
     where diff >= 5 
     group by id;

        ID         COUNT
---------- -------------
        22             2
        23             2
```

[Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3237d3f3d5808874cb234752fcd009c0) is the fiddle.

For more about `LAG()`

**Documentation:** [LAG](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions094.htm#SQLRF00652)